# Token issue when attempting to login laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4, token

So I have a login function posted below that works great, no issues most of the time. However on the homepage for whatever reason if you try and login it does not authenticate you and changes the url to the following

```
http://localhost/?_token=Jh36AX6sx0qhzOniPoMSn3pROCAVombCn4xKzoJm&email=admin%40admin.com&password=testpass
```

This makes no sense to me, it throws some weird error and shows the email and password in plain text. Does anyone know what is going on? I use the exact same function on any other page and it works fine, but not the homepage. The only other time I have seen the url do something similar is when setting up and doing password reset stuff. Any ideas?

```
public function doLogin()
    {
        // validate the info, create rules for the inputs
        $rules = array(
            'email1'    => 'required|email', // make sure the email is an actual email
            'password1' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3' // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 3 characters
        );
        // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
        if ($validator->fails()) 
        {
            return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('password1')); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
        } 
        else 
        {
            // create our user data for the authentication
            $userdata = array(
                'email'     => Input::get('email1'),
                'password'  => Input::get('password1')
            );

            // attempt to do the login
            if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) 
            {

                return Redirect::to('profile');
            } 
            else 
            {       
                $this->layout->content = View::make('login')->with('p', 'Incorrect Login Information');
            }

        }
    }
```

As requested this is the form that is calling the function, it is using POST

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'class' => 'form form-horizontal' ,'method' => 'post')) }}
{{ Form::text('email1', Input::old('email1'), array('class'=>'form-control','placeholder' => 'Email Address')) }}
{{ Form::password('password1', array('class'=>'form-control','placeholder' => 'Password')) }}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Login</button><br><br>
{{ HTML::link('login/fb', 'Sign-in with Facebook',array('class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control facebook')) }}
{{ HTML::link('password/remind', 'Forgot Password?') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Can you show your controller method which is being used to display the `login` form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your form is using `GET` instead of `POST`. I would recommend posting your form code to verify this. When you switch it to `POST`, make sure your routes are setup to handle it as a `POST` request as well.

Comment: This is why I am so confused, I never use get anywhere in my application. I can show you the code that is activating this form in the main edited post. And to top it off the get of the login just shows a view, so this makes even less sense

Comment: Is that the correct form? I'm seeing `email1` and `password1` instead of `email` and `password` in your URL.

Comment: Thats my main question I have no idea how that url is getting generated, That token is nothing I am doing. I have also tried changing everything back to email and password without the 1, same issue

Comment: Mind posting your routes? You definitely have something weird going on. Even your form is supposed to be submitting to `login` url, but that doesn't appear to be happening. Btw, what is the "weird error" you are referring to?

Comment: Found the issue, Apparently the ?_token= is something laravel normally does on the backend, they keep track of tokens for every form Apparently what was going on is I opened a <form> on this page but did not close it. this caused it to not work. If anyone runs into this in the future check if all your forms are closed </form>